# LETOR data sets, which contain the queries and documents?

Tags: dataset

While researching information retrieval evaluation, I found [LETOR](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/beijing/projects/letor/letor4dataset.aspx). This is a test collection used for evaluation of ranking algorithms. Since the data contains relevance judgements for queries, it can also be used as a test collection for information retrieval evaluation (precision, recall...).

I checked the whole site, but didn't find the queries and the documents, which are the foundation for the relevance judgements. **Where can I find the actual data?**

(I am afraid it is not freely available)

Comment: I really, really doubt you'll be able to find this both from a privacy standpoint and from a secrecy standpoint.

Comment: But if I pay for them, I will get them.

Comment: Wait, so are you saying they're available for purchase but that you just don't want to pay for them so you're looking to get them for free? Or that you know that they're available for purchase but can't find where? If the former, I'm pretty sure that's not an appropriate question for CV. If the latter, I stand by my original comment.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm at a university. Every paper, that evaluates the performance of an IR algorithm uses those (or similar) data sets. Unfortunately (what I've found out until now), is that this data costs money (me == poor student). However, I heard from several people that for academic usage, you could obtain older versions of the data sets for free. Still haven't found out whether that's true.

I'm not trying to obtain something that costs money for free. I am trying to find out, whether there's a LEGAL possibility to get some of those data sets for free for academic use.